# py3k: Maximum Number In Given List - short form

Tags: python, python-3.x

We are given list of numbers *l* , example:

```
l=[5,2,4,3]
```

What is short form of extracting maximum number - in other words - short form of this:

```
x=l[0]
for i in l:
   if x<i : x=i
```

**?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for the [`max()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#maxi) function.

```
>>> my_list = [5, 2, 4, 3]
>>> max(my_list)
5
```